# Opening Excel files in multiple monitors

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-monitors

I have three monitors that need three separate excel files displayed.  When I run the following code on a Office 365 machine it works.  When I open it on a Office 2010 machine it does not function properly.  Is there code to work around the 2010 limitation or do I need to upgrade to get the VBA code to function?  Is there cleaner code to use?

```
'Open first furnace
Workbooks.Open ("z:\Heat Treat\FURNACE #1.xlsm")
With ActiveWindow
 .WindowState = xlNormal
 .Top = 1
 .Left = 1621
End With 
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

'Open second furnace
Workbooks.Open ("z:\Heat Treat\FURNACE #2.xlsm")
With ActiveWindow
 .WindowState = xlNormal
 .Top = 1
 .Left = 2252
End With
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized

'Open third furnace
Workbooks.Open ("z:\Heat Treat\FURNACE #3.xlsm")
With ActiveWindow
 .WindowState = xlNormal
 .Top = 1
 .Left = 1
End With
Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
```

Comment: *A lot* has changed between Office 2010 and Office 365; see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/troubleshoot/excel/force-excel-to-open-new-instance)

Comment: Looks like it might be time to upgrade, least then I can run my code.  Thanks for the information.